# Which kind of random variable it is appropriate for a driver getting accident in a period of time?

Tags: probability

I encountered a exercise problem listed below:

The probability that a driver will have an accident in 1 month is 0.02. Find the probability that he will have 3 accidents in 100 months.

I am thinking of a random variable that will best describe the situation. It seems that I should pick exponential random variable, but it looks like can also be a pdf with linear function of time. Can anyone tell me what is the best choice to model this situation?

Comment: I'd go with [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: Note:  as stated, the underlying problem is ambiguous.  Did you mean $\textit {exactly}$ $3$ or $\textit {at least}$?

Comment: I copied the exact wording from that exam. So, I have no idea either. What are the differences?

Comment: Would you please explain how to do it with Poisson?

Comment: The beauty of Poisson is that the means behave as you'd expect.  If the mean is $.02$ per month then the mean in $100$ months is $100\times .02=2$.  And the mean determines the process.   In this case, since (presumably) the probability of multiple accidents in a month is very low, this should be very close to the answer given by the binomial process.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried using Poisson random variable. And this is what I have: $p_{X}(k)=e^{-\lambda }\frac{\lambda ^{k}}{k!}$ with $\lambda$ as number of month and k as number of failures. And I end up having $p_{X}(k)=e^{-1}$. Obviously, the probability is not 0.02 (0.367). I am confused!

Comment: With a mean of $2$, the poisson distribution gives $P(x=3)=\frac {e^{-2}2^3}{3!}=0.180447044$.

Comment: To stress:  It is not clear whether you meant "exactly $3$" or "at least $3$".  The numerical answer I gave was for "exactly $3$".

Comment: I see. But the point is, how does your result related to the fact that P(X=1)=0.02?

Comment: As I explained earlier...since the one month mean is $.02$ the $100$ month mean is $100\times .02=2$.

Comment: So, that 0.02 is mean? But the question states that it is the probability of getting 1 accident in one month.... This question is really confusing...

Comment: That's the same thing.  If the probability of having an accident in a month is $.02$ then over $100$ months you expect to have $2$ accidents.

Comment: Yes. That is what I think if mean is 0.02 accidents. But then what is the meaning using Poisson random variable which has $\lambda$ (number of month) as mean? that mean is the month, rather than number of accidents.

Comment: I don't understand.  The random variable here is the number of accidents in a given period.  I think you need to review the basics.

Comment: No offense. I understood your idea about using Poisson random variable to model the situation until I saw that mean is 0.02 accidents because the question states that it is the probability of getting 1 accident in a month instead. I did look at the basic definition and that is contradict to your idea. I think there is something wrong here.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the mean of a probability distribution?

Comment: I do, but as I realized, this question has nothing to do with mean.

Comment: So, if, in a single month,  you can have $1$ accident with probability $.02$ and $0$ accidents with probability, what is the mean number of accidents?

Comment: The mean is 2. So? I mean how does this mean relate to the probability of 3 accidents in 100 month? 3 is close to mean, and is there any significance?

Comment: The mean is not $2$.  Try again.  You have $1$ accident with probability $.02$ and $0$ accents with probability $1-.02=.98$, so the mean is...?

Comment: This is what you said above: "The beauty of Poisson is that the means behave as you'd expect. If the mean is .02 per month then the mean in 100 months is 100×.02=2." in the fifth comment. I just read it out from your comment. Now it is different...

Comment: For Heaven's sakes.  Earlier, I was speaking of the mean over $100$ months.  In the latest comments, I was speaking of one month.  Nothing I have written has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is implementing the Binomial brute force method described above:

Let $X_{i}$ be number of accidents in a month, and we have

$$p_{X_{i}}(k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Also, we are given that $p_{X_{1}}(1)=\frac{1!}{1!(1-1)!}p^{1}(1-p)^{0}=p=0.02$

We are looking for $S_{100}=X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{100}$

$$P(S_{100}=k)=\binom{100}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

With k=3,

$$P(S_{100}=3)=\binom{100}{3}(0.02)^{3}(0.98)^{97}=0.18$$

Using poisson approximation for Binomial random variable, we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\binom{100}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{\lambda ^{k}e^{-\lambda }}{k!}=\frac{2 ^{3}e^{-2}}{3!}=0.18$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ describe "having an accident the $i$th month". It's a Bernoulli B(0.02). Set $$S_{100}=X_1+...+X_{100}.$$ 
$S_{100}$ is a binomial $Bin(100,0.02)$. You wish to estimate
$$\mathbb P(S_{100}=3).$$
That can be compute brute force, or using Poisson approximation.

Comment: Please explain what a binomial (100,0.02) is. I tried to find the expression of sum of Bernoulli random variables, but I have not able to find it. Without this expression, I have no way of brutally computing it into Poisson approximation.

Comment: it's binomiale with parameter $n=100$ and $p=0.02$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Lulu for give me hints about how to proceed with Poisson random variable

I am using Poisson Random Variable to solve this problem (will attempt using Binomial brute force method later)

Given that

$$p_{X}(1)=e^{-\lambda }\frac{\lambda ^{1}}{1!}=0.02$$

We are looking for the probability when n = 100, k=3, $\lambda=np = 2$

$$p_{X}(100)=e^{-2}\frac{2 ^{3}}{3!}\approx 0.18$$

Using Binomial approximation with $\lambda=np=2, n=100, k=3, p=0.02$ we have

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{100!}{3!97!}(0.02)^{3}(0.98)97\approx 0.18$$